# Going to tab content by clicking main navigation

Tags: jquery, html

I don't know if this can be done with html but this is what I want to do.

I using foundation's **[tab](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html)** and I want to navigate to any of the **tab's content** by clicking the links on the main navigation. The content of these sub-menus in the navigation are all on the same page. Please let me know if you don't understand so I can upload an image or something. the is the [**link to it**](http://bmmisrq.com/bmmi-beta/the-corporation.html).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have all the content for the sub-menus on one HTML page and dynamically show or hide them based on the link the user clicked?  Yes this is very simple with Javascript or jQuery.  Is your question about the JS code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1**: I have have time to study how Foundation works. So I can make a more educated solution. My original idea was to mimic the effect of clicking on the items at css level.

This doesn't mean that the old solution didn't work. In fact the end result of both solutions in the same. I have tested both the old and the new solution on a copy of the HTML of your site.

Also took the opportunity to add some clarifications.

**Edit 2**: I have added control over the broser history. This means that the code will change the url that the user sees and will handle tha back button correctly, all without reloading the page.

### Roadmap

You have to do these:

1. Adding an id to handle the tabs.
2. Creating a JavaScript function `selectTab` to switch among them. *depending on the solution you choose*.
3. Creating a JavaScript function `navigateTab` that will call `selectTab` but also update the browser history.
4. Adding the click event handlers.
5. Handle the back button.

So, let's get the common parts first:

---

### Adding an id to handle the tabs

HTML:

```
<dl id="LOOK_MY_ID" class="tabs" data-tab>
    <dd class="active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
        <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
        <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel2-3">
        <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel2-4">
        <p>Fourth panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note*: this is based on the HTML presented in the [Example of Foundation Tabs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html). In your code you would add the id to the div that has the class `corporation-frame`.

---

### Creating the helper function

The purpose of the helper function is to make the click event handlers easier while abstracting the code to change the browser url. We get arround this as seen below.

JavaScript:

```
function navigateTab(event)
{
    var url = $(event.target).attr('href');
    var target = url.split('#')[1];
    if (target.substr(0, 3) == 'tab')
    {
        var state = {tab: target.substr(3)};
        selectTab("LOOK_MY_ID", state.tab); //<-- change the tab
        history.pushState(state, null, url); //<-- change the url
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

As you can see it uses `event`, the reason behind this is that we are going to use this function directly as a click event handler. Also the tab to choose and the url to put are taken from the `href` attribute of the hyperlink that was clicked.

This technique also allows to safetly add the click event handler to all the links at once.

*Note*: we are changing the url by making use of the [HTML5's History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

---

### Adding the event handlers

You *need* to add an event handler to your links (Foundation add those to the tabs behind the scenes, we are going to mimic that for your menus).

There are two methods to add those event handler...

**Method A)**

Select your anchors and add the event handler via JavaScript:

```
$('ul.dropdown a').on("click", navigateTab);
```

It doesn't get any simpler than that.

*Note*: make sure to use the correct selector to select the hyperlinks from your menus. Also you may need (if you add your script on top of the page) to add this with `ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('ul.dropdown a').on("click", navigateTab);
    }
);
```

**Method B)**

Add the event handler directly on the HTML:

HTML:

```
<a href="#tab3" onclick="navigateTab(event)">Tab 3</a>
```

*Note 1*: If JavaScript is disabled on the handler don't work, it will make the page jump to the contents (if they are visible). That's the best you can get without JavaScript.

---

### Handling the back button

In the previous code we are not only changing the url in the browser, but also we are adding an entry in the navigation history of the page... so, what happens when the user click back? Well, we are going to handle the back button, again by making use of [HTML5's History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

To handle that we are going to add this code:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event)
{
    selectTab("LOOK_MY_ID", event.state.tab); //<-- change the tab
};
```

This is why we should not change the url from `selectTab`, because if we do... we won't be able to navigate back!

*note*: this code doesn't only take care of the back button, but any navigation in the browser history inside of the page.

---

## NEW SOLUTION

---

### Creating a JavaScript function to switch among them

The function `selectTab` will be implemented by:

1. Mimic what Foundation does (based on actual code from Foundation):

JavaScript:

```
function selectTab(id, tab)
{
    // activate only the right tab:
    var tab = $("#" + id + " > dl > dd:nth-child(" + tab + ")");
    var a = $("a", tab);
    target = $('#' + a.attr("href").split('#')[1]);
    siblings = tab.siblings();
    settings = tab.closest('[data-tab]').data('tab-init');

    tab.addClass(settings.active_class);
    siblings.removeClass(settings.active_class);
    target.siblings().removeClass(settings.active_class).end().addClass(settings.active_class);
}
```

---

## OLD SOLUTION

---

### Creating a JavaScript function to switch among them

The function `selectTab` will be implemented by:

1. Make tab you want active
2. Make the corresponding content active
3. Make all other tabs not active
4. Make all other contents not active

JavaScript:

```
function selectTab(id, tab)
{
    // activate only the right tab:
    $("#" + id + " > dl").children().each
    (
        function(index, element)
        {
            if (index == tab)
            {
                $(element).addClass("active");
            }
            else
            {
                $(element).removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    );
    // activate only the right content:
    $("#" + id + " > div").children().each
    (
        function(index, element)
        {
            if (index == tab)
            {
                $(element).addClass("active");
            }
            else
            {
                $(element).removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: We don't need to worry about the 'tab content' because this is bound to the 'tab' so when we click the tab, it becomes 'active' showing the content bound to it. At the moment when you navigate the tab's link the url doesn't change. I just need a target url for the tabs.

Comment: Hi Theraot! Sorry to bother you again but I'm not seeing the url changing. What am I doing wrong? This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/F8nBY/2/embedded/result/ . Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Labanino because it is not navigating. This is because the click of the hyperlinks is being handled by JavaScript and it is preventing the default behaviour to execute (this prevents the page to jump). If you want to make the url change while handling the click on javascript and without jumping? Ok... can be done with HTML5's History API.

Comment: @Labanino See the updates. In the new code the navigation is readed form the `href` of the `a` tags, so make sure to have that right. As previouly I have tested this on an offline copy.

Comment: would you mind checking the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/F8nBY/6/ to see whats going on? Please. Sorry man I'm just a bloody designer. Thanks.

Comment: @Labanino Working version here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/F8nBY/8/show/   with alternative menu here: http://jsfiddle.net/F8nBY/9/show/ Points of interest: 1) Look at the freaking id, where it is placed! 2) make sure to have the href right, 3) jsfiddle wraps the javascript, so `navigateTab` and `selectTab` are out of context from `onclick` (this is jsfiddle's fault) [added `navigateTab` to `window` as workaround], 4) jsfiddle is not perfect (neither codepen), sometimes you have to do offline tests, how hard is to type the code in a text editor and open it in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the active class from the tab

```
$("#tab1").removeClass("active");
```

Add the class to the new tab

```
$("#tab2").addClass("active");
```

Hide the first panel

```
$("#panel1").hide();
```

Show new panel

```
$("#panel2").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use an on click function on your navigation bar to set the class of the required tab to "active"

```
$("navelement").on("click", function(){
    $("#tab_id").addClass("active");
}
```